# Sorting float values for averages

Tags: c, bit

I know generally why it would be advisable to sort a float at all in order to calculate the average of several values in array: you would risk adding together values that are farther apart gap-wise - and thus distort the overall value.

But why would the accuracy further increase if you decided to order them not in ascending order, but descending order? I've come across a few average formulations for floats and have noticed a preference to sort them in descending order and wondered why this is so?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti when dealing with limited-precision types such as `float`, sorting can and will make a difference, due to rounding errors at different stages. As an example, take the average of `0.2f`, `0.4f`, and `16777216.0f`. Summing in increasing order gives `0.6f + 16777216.0f`, which rounds to `16777217.0f`. Summing in decreasing gives `(16777216.0f + 0.4f) + 0.2f` -> `16777216.0f + 0.2f` -> `16777216.0f`, which is a different sum.

Comment: Are the algorithms always summing from 0..n-1?  You could easily sort ascending and then sum from n-1..0 for the same effect.  Also are the floats always greater than 0?  I would have felt that you'd want to sum from small absolute values to large, to collect the small floats into something that may be significant when combined with the larger ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of truncation errors.

Assume that your floating-point arithmetic just stores four significant digits.

7.000 + 0.0003 + 0.0003 + 0.0003 + 0.0003 yields 7.000, 7.000, 7.000, 7.000.

while

0.0003 + 0.0003 + 0.0003 + 0.0003 + 7.000 yields 0.0006, 0.0009, 0.0012, 7.001.

When you add a small number to a much bigger one, the last decimals get lost. When the numbers are balanced, this effect is lessened.

Comment: Also, depending on rounding, your first example could yield 7, 7.001, 7.002, 7.003.

Comment: Right, I am changing the example with 0.0003.

Comment: I believe the OP is seeing algorithms using descending order, large to small.

Comment: @dohashi: the more accurate is increasing order, small to large. I am not fully sure, but large to small should be the worst. And all of this holds for positive numbers only.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I agree that increasing order seems like the right choice, but the OP is asking because he is seeing algorithms using descending.

Comment: @dohasi: the OP should confirm his statement, this is unlikely.